# Identify which queries an Access 1997 report is using to generate?

Tags: ms-access, report

I am updating an Microsoft Access 1997 mdb. I want to find out how one of the reports are generated and I am not sure which queries the program uses to generate the report. I am only able to access the design and preview mode or the report.

Is there an easy way to identify how the report is generated? Specifically which queries, tables, etc are used.

Comment: Does the report record source not help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the report design view, view the report's properties, then the recordSource property